# Reset math font style from bold to 'normal'

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pdftex

I have a question on reverting a bold math font to the 'normal' math font style. Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ricciPerm}{\bm{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\idx}[2]{{\mathrm{#1}}_{\scriptsize{#2}}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
            \idx{\ricciPerm}{ijk} A_{jk} &= x_i\\
            \ricciPerm : \bm{A} &= \bm{x}
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The compiled version looks so:
[image]

In the context  of my dissertation, I need to consistently convert between bold-faced and 'normal' math font styles. In the example, in the indexed notation, the calligraphic E should be in the non-bold font style, like the 'A' next to it.

I would like the `\idx` command to be able to convert any bold-faced symbols into light-faced ones. As you see in this MWE, I tried the `\mathrm` command to try to do this, but doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me with this simple problem.

Thanks,

Kavi

Comment: If both calligraphic E mean the same, they should also look the same - in math look matters. If they mean something different, define a dedicated command  for the light variant.

Comment: BTW: your use of `\scriptsize` should give you warnings, this is a text command not suitable for math mode. Thre really should not be any need to explicitly change the size there (BTW2 `\scriptsize` does not take any arguments it is an on switch)

Comment: Thanks for the `\let\bm\relax` tip. While it worked for the calligraphic E, it also affected a variable (`r`) where it should have not. I've updated the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is convention in computational-mechanics to distinguish between bold- and light-faced fonts when referring to the tensors in the matrix and index notations.

Comment: Then your commands should reflect this meaning. It is not good to have a confusing mix  of commands like \mathrm and \bm and some commands with meaning. Get a better logic in it. @egreg's answer shows what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a proper alias for `\bm`, but which changes its action when in the scope of `\idx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\tensor}[1]{\ifidx#1\else\bm{#1}\fi}

\newcommand{\ricciPerm}{\tensor{\mathcal{E}}}
\newcommand{\idx}[2]{\begingroup\idxtrue #1\endgroup_{#2}}
\newif\ifidx

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\idx{\ricciPerm}{ijk} \idx{\tensor{A}}{jk} &= x_i\\
\ricciPerm : \tensor{A} &= \bm{x}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\DeclareMathOperator` is not the right way to define `\ricciPerm`, which is just an ordinary symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still have a problem with your suggestion failing to typeset the `r` bold-faced in the new example. I've edited the MWE. Please have a look.

Comment: @kane Why are you using `\DeclareMathOperator`? Moreover, I didn't suggest `\let\bm\relax`, did I?

Comment: Aha! I got that wrong! Your suggestion works with replacing the `DeclareMathOperator` with `newcommand`. Thanks. I'll accept your answer. BTW, should I change the MWE replacing the 'declare' command with the 'newcommand' for other viewers? I'm kinda new here.

Comment: @kane You shouldn't have modified the question to add a “working” solution. Please, roll back.